# Throw 404 when requesting file unless HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I need to create a condition in my .htaccess file that will give a 404 when a user requests a file over HTTP, but not when they request it over HTTPS. I have about 15 files in the same directory that this needs to happen with (but not the others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) with a status of `404` on those locations.

Comment: part of my problem is writing the condition

Comment: Ah, you're using `.htaccess` files. In that case you'll have to use mod_rewrite, with `RewriteCond` checking the value of `%{HTTPS}`. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond